# Is the IIF SQL Function Supported in SAP Business One/HANA?

Tags: sql, hana

I've been trying to write more queries by hand rather than use the built in SQL Query Generator found in SAP Business one, and found a weird issue when I try to use `IIF`.

When I try to run this, I get a syntax error "SQL Syntax error: incorrect syntax near "=" ... 'User-Defined Values'"

```
    IIF(T0."ItemCode" = 'Shipping Charges', T0."PriceBefDi", T0."Quantity" * T4."AvgPrice") As "TotalLineCost"
```

A `CASE` statement (shown here) works, but not the `IIF`.

```
CASE
    WHEN T0."ItemCode" = 'Shipping Charges'
    THEN T0."PriceBefDi"
    ELSE T0."Quantity" * T4."AvgPrice"
END AS "TotalLineCost"
```

Is the IIF function not supported in SAP Business one/HANA database? Or is it just my syntax?

Thank you!

Comment: https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/f12b86a6284c4aeeb449e57eb5dd3ebd.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edward is correct. IFF is not available on this specific SQL server. `CASE` is portable across all SQL platforms whereas `IIF` is SQL SERVER 2012+ specific.

Replacing the `IIF` with a `CASE` is the correct solution and functions mostly the same.

[Supporting Information](https://www.encyclopedia-excel.com/sql-case-statement-the-iif-alternative-for-sap-business-one-hana-databases)